# Getting error in django at the time of migration

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

```
from django.db import models
class Note(models.Model):
    subject=models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    My_Thought= models.TextField(blank = False)
```

At the time of migration, I am getting the following error executing this command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to note without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
>   Select an option:

As you know I am not adding id, because it is automatically generated by django, then why I am getting this?

Comment: Add default="" or null=True to the new field you just added to the model after already migrating.

Comment: Or just try deleting the existing migration files and DB if its a new project

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, the problem is not here, I've just tried to create the model in an empty app and it works fine!

Comment: This does not help.  The OP is applying changes to an already existing database, not a new empty app.

Comment: @AlanHoover it give error to the `id` field which is not included in the model, there is an error in a preexisting migration (the OP should check the DB manually, I think the OP corrupted the PK field)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening when Django tries to modify existing models so it needs data.

Simply change your code to something like:

```
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model):
    subject=models.CharField(max_length = 100, default="something or leave empty")

    My_Thought= models.TextField(blank = False, default="")
```

If the error doesn't come from this snippet, then maybe you have another model throwing this error.